# Running Docker inside IntelliJ for AWS Lambda App : Docker throws 404 Client Error (docker.errors.ImageNotFound)

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, aws-lambda

**Problem**

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/key-tasks.html

OS: Win 10 Pro 64 Bit

Maven:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-28T01:06:16+10:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_221, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Java:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName>java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

C:\Users\MyUserName>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_221
```

Docker (is installed and running):

```
C:\Users\MyUserName>docker -v
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

Docker settings in IntelliJ Docker Plugin:

- File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker:
- TCP socket > Engine API URL: tcp://localhost:2375

Docker Desktop config:

- Docker daemon started with checkbox checked: "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS"

Exception when running the Lambda function via the Lambda symbol on the App.java (full log is provided at the end of the post):

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.35/containers/create
```

**Expected output**: Lambda function is deployed to local Docker container and runs.

When running the Docker command manually, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName>docker run lambci/lambda:java8
Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:java8' locally
java8: Pulling from lambci/lambda
docker: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I don't get this error when Docker is run from within IntelliJ.

Full output from IntelliJ log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" local invoke --template C:\Users\MyUserName\dev\IdeaProjects\Serverless-Project-01\HelloWorldFunction\.aws-sam\build\template.yaml --event "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\[Local] HelloWorldFunction-event.json" HelloWorldFunction
Invoking helloworld.App::handleRequest (java8)
2019-10-05 22:46:08 Found credentials in environment variables.

Fetching lambci/lambda:java8 Docker container image.....
Mounting C:\Users\MyUserName\dev\IdeaProjects\Serverless-Project-01\HelloWorldFunction\.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localnpipe/v1.35/containers/create

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli(prog_name="sam")
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metrics.py", line 93, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metrics.py", line 62, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\invoke\cli.py", line 90, in cli
    parameter_overrides,
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\invoke\cli.py", line 150, in do_cli
    context.function_name, event=event_data, stdout=context.stdout, stderr=context.stderr
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\lib\local_lambda.py", line 97, in invoke
    self.local_runtime.invoke(config, event, debug_context=self.debug_context, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\lambdafn\runtime.py", line 83, in invoke
    self._container_manager.run(container)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\manager.py", line 93, in run
    container.create()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\container.py", line 134, in create
    real_container = self.docker_client.containers.create(self._image, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\models\containers.py", line 861, in create
    resp = self.client.api.create_container(**create_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 429, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 440, in create_container_from_config
    return self._result(res, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.ImageNotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such image: lambci/lambda:java8")
```

I'm quite new to all this, so any support is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just faced with this error myself

1. Right click on the Docker Desktop icon in windows tray
2. Select "Switch to Linux Containers"